# How to find out what exactly triggers digest cycle in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, performance, performance-testing, angularjs-digest

I encountered performance problems with my AngularJS application on IE and started analyzing the root cause for this. The root cause seems to be, that too many watchers are used, ng-repeat is used for a table with a large amount of data, almost no one-way-data-binding is being used and static data is not being cached. So in general I found out, that it's not just an IE problem.

However, I also started to analyze the digest circle and tried to keep track of it:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
  count += 1;
  console.log('Count: ', count);
});
```

According to my console output, the digest cycle triggers every 1s.
This is very, very problematic in my eyes, because from what I have read so far it should only trigger in certain cases and not continuously. Well, there is a timed request for data, but it's only every 10 seconds...but maybe some change triggers another and so on.

I would like to find out which part of my code triggers the digest cycle, is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

---

### Update

The problem was not caused by the view containing the table, I found a hidden

```
$interval(function () { ... }, 1000)
```

somewhere else, which causes the digest cycle to trigger every second.

Comment: would be nice to see more code, mainly how `ng-repeat` is used (or see how big is your data)

Comment: I realize that I need to fix the table aswell. It's simply used like `ng-repeat="row in $data | tableFilter:filters`
but even without any data available the digest cycle triggers every second :/

Comment: I would like to present you more code, but it's a company project

Comment: you can check where you have watchers (from console) with [this code by Kent C. Dodds](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef). Once you find them, either fix them yourself, or describe here in details. You can also try to make an example that will reproduce your issue in online editors like JSFiddle / Plunker / etc.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and try it out.
And from my understanding so far, it's not easy to find out which model change or event triggers a certain digest cycle?

Comment: using filters on a big set of data will lag it for use, but I don't think it should trigger itself every digest cycle on its own

Comment: I even removed the table entirely from the view and it still triggers every second. The problem certainly goes deeper. Maybe I will find out something more interesting with your provided snippet! :P

Maybe my code to keep track of the digest cycle is wrong?

Comment: update: found the f$%§ing `$interval(function () { ... }, 1000);` which triggers the digest cycle every second...jeez...the view containing the table was not the problem....initial question is obsolete and resolved.

am I right that by reducing the watchers and triggering the digest loop less often, I will end up with a better performance? :P

Comment: to update the model, once the data was changed, it needs to watch them ("*them*" meaning with two-way data-binding). You *might* be able to use one-way data-binding with this trick: `ng-repeat="row in ::$data" ng-show="([row] | tableFilter:filters).length"` and `{{::row}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was planning to do this kind of one-way-binding. Sadly it doesn't work, my table stays empty. My guess is, that at the moment the one-way-binding takes place `$data` is not yet available/filled.

is there an easy workaround?

Comment: Angular's one way binding (using `::`) will only bind the first time that the value becomes something other than `null` or `undefined`. So if you initialize `$data` to an empty array or something, that will take the first bind and it will never be bound again once the data is updated.

Comment: thanks! Same problem